macs3 to detect high coverage regions in long-reads
I am using macs3 to detect regions with high number of reads, similar to macs3's goal - detect chip-seq peaks - as it has been used for long-reads data, I would like to ask how to determine if it is doing a proper call or detecting spuriously peaks. The peaks are analyzed through IGV visualization.

Can you please provide more context around your study, especially examples of outputs / peaks? It's hard to answer this without knowing what data you have.
